# Run testthat tests on build and reload

Tags: r, rstudio, testthat

Is there a way to run `testthat` tests on build and reload in RStudio? Is it possible to run only a subset of tests?

I find myself writing a test, making a change, build+reload, then manually running tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test your package with Ctrl/Cmd + Shift + T or devtools::test().

Here is a good link about it too.
http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/tests.html

Comment: Hehe, almost then. I did my best. Good luck!